# ToolTip's BackColor varies for two different samples without using any BackColor property

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, tooltip

I have used ToolTip in two different c# windows forms samples. 
The BackColor for the ToolTip varies for these samples as given below.

[ToolTip with yellow BackColor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rIbJe.png)

[ToolTip with white BackColor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xVKWZ.png)

I haven't set any BackColor property for both. But the BackColor for the ToolTip varies for these two sample. I have used the below code to set ToolTip.

**Sample1:**

`ToolTip toolTip1 = new ToolTip();
 toolTip1.SetToolTip(button1, "Button");`

**Sample2:**

```
ToolTip toolTip2 = new ToolTip();
toolTip2.SetToolTip(button1, "Button");
```

Please provide me your answers for this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Those two images look identical.  What am I missing here?

Comment: The tool tip colors are still the same.

Comment: i have changed the picture The first one will be in yellow.

Comment: They're both still yellow.

Comment: Sorry I don't know what the problem was. For me the links provide the appropriate images.

Comment: They're two different images now, yes.  But the tool tips are the same color.  The text in one is a little lighter than the other, but that's about it.

Comment: I don't know whether the image looks as you said. But when I run the samples the BackColor was entirely different in these two forms.

Comment: @rory.ap The colors are a bit different, also paying attention to different visual styles of buttons will solve the puzzle.

Comment: @RezaAghaei -- strange, I was on my laptop screen before and now that I'm docked and looking at the monitor, I can definitely see the difference.  I thought I was maybe going color blind :)

Comment: @rory.ap :))) the color difference is not obvious specially on a form with default back color. To be honest I could't differentiate between colors at first glance but I guessed what is happening!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like other themed controls, the appearance of `ToolTip` is dependent to theme and visual styles. The appearance of it is different if you enable or disable visual styles.

**Without Visual Styles**

[image]

**With Visual Styles**

[image]

Currently in your examples:

- The yellow one which doesn't have shadow, shows the `ToolTip` when visual styles are disabled.
- The lighter one which has shadow, shows the `ToolTip` when visual styles are enabled.

Also appearance of buttons in screenshots confirms this.

Look in `Main` method in `Program.cs` and to enable visual styles, you should have this code `Application.EnableVisualStyles();` before showing the start up form. Or if you don't need visual styles, comment/remove it.

Comment: Thank you Mr. Reza Aghaei. Now It Looks similar in both the forms.  Thank you so much